# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined even after passing 'form' in render_template

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have made a WTForm but couldn't load it. I had made a similar form like this in a different project from where I just copied the code and changed it's details accordingly. But now it's showing **'form' undefined** Error.
The code for which the error is occurring is given below:

```py
c = [('COMPANY','COMPANY'),('DISTRIBUTOR','DISTRIBUTOR'),('OUTLET','OUTLET')]

@app.route('/') # Decorator to create url routing, '/' = Home route
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# User Registration
class Registration(Form):
    reg_name = StringField('Name',[validators.Length(min=5,max=20), validators.DataRequired()])
    reg_email = StringField('Email',[validators.DataRequired()])
    reg_category = SelectField(label='Category', choices=c)
    reg_password = PasswordField('Password',[validators.Length(min=5,max=15), validators.DataRequired(), validators.EqualTo('reg_confirm', message='Password do not match')])
    reg_confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = Registration(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template('index.html',form=form)
```

This is my **app.py** script

```
<span class="col-md-6 float-right">
        {% from 'includes/_formhelpers.html' import render_field %}
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <div class="form-group">{{render_field(form.reg_name, class_="form-control")}}</div>
            <div class="form-group">{{render_field(form.reg_email, class_="form-control")}}</div>
            <div class="form-group">{{render_field(form.reg_category, class_="form-control")}}</div>
            <div class="form-group">{{render_field(form.reg_password, class_="form-control")}}</div>
            <div class="form-group">{{render_field(form.reg_confirm, class_="form-control")}}</div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </span>
```

And this is the **index.html** where I am trying to render the form.

Comment: Your `index()` method renders the `index.html` template but doesn't pass a form in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.html` is rendered by view function `index` and `register`. But you forgot to pass the `form` instance in view `index`.